# C#: The application reading files from Fat32 disk resulting VM restarts

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, fat32

I'm currently reading files that are stored on FAT32 persistent disk on GCP. The disk is attached to a windows VM in read-only movie where the c# app reads the files. On starting the application, the VM crashes but when the disk is attached in Read-write mode then app don't experience any issues. There is a need to attach the disk in read-only mode as the disk needs to be accessed by multiple VMs to access the files. Dump of the crash:
Env: Windows
dotnet version: 6.0.

```
CACHE_MANAGER (34)
    See the comment for FAT_FILE_SYSTEM (0x23)
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000551
Arg2: ffffffffc0000420
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2296

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 5020

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3827

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 68539

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 87

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.InsufficientDumpfileSize
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.RequiredDumpfileSize
    Value: 0x4f031cd8
```

PROCESS_NAME:  dotnet.exe

STACK_TEXT:
ffffb808`c3d4f108 fffff806`6d89cf73     : 00000000`00000034 00000000`00000551 ffffffff`c0000420 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb808`c3d4f110 fffff806`6dc88254     : 00000000`00000000 ffff950b`00000001 ffffb808`c3d4f220 ffffb808`c3d4f238 : nt!CcGetVirtualAddress+0x196103
ffffb808`c3d4f1b0 fffff80c`7373779c     : ffffb808`00000000 ffff950b`89906a40 ffffb808`c3d4f338 ffffb808`c3d4f2a0 : nt!CcMapData+0x74
ffffb808`c3d4f220 fffff80c`73736422     : 00000000`00445000 ffffb808`c3d4f2c0 00000000`fffffffe fffff80c`7375181d : fastfat!FatReadVolumeFile+0x4c
ffffb808`c3d4f260 fffff80c`7373498d     : ffff950b`89906a40 00000017`46ea0000 00000000`00000020 ffff838c`032a7010 : fastfat!FatLookupFatEntry+0x16e
ffffb808`c3d4f2c0 fffff80c`73735112     : ffff950b`89906a40 00000000`00000000 ffff838c`032a7028 ffffb808`c3d4f3f8 : fastfat!FatLookupFileAllocation+0x1d5
ffffb808`c3d4f390 fffff80c`73737c12     : ffff838c`032a7010 ffff950b`85799b00 ffff838c`00000000 00000000`00000000 : fastfat!FatLookupFileAllocationSize+0x3e
ffffb808`c3d4f3e0 fffff80c`73737887     : ffff838c`032a7010 ffff838c`032a7010 ffff838c`12655e01 00000000`00000000 : fastfat!FatOpenDirectoryFile+0x26
ffffb808`c3d4f430 fffff80c`73745268     : ffffb808`c3d4f500 fffff806`6d863644 00000000`00000504 00000000`00000000 : fastfat!FatReadDirectoryFile+0x23
ffffb808`c3d4f480 fffff80c`7375c5ea     : ffff838c`12655d70 ffffb808`c3d4f678 ffff838c`12655e24 ffff950b`84dc7740 : fastfat!FatGetDirentFromFcbOrDcb+0x4c
ffffb808`c3d4f4d0 fffff80c`7375c1ce     : ffff838c`12655d70 ffff838c`12655d70 ffff838c`12655d70 00000000`00000000 : fastfat!FatDetermineAndMarkFcbCondition+0x66
ffffb808`c3d4f550 fffff80c`73758624     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff950b`85799b80 ffff950b`89906a40 : fastfat!FatVerifyFcb+0xea
ffffb808`c3d4f590 fffff80c`73715978     : ffff950b`89906a40 ffff950b`85799b80 ffff950b`85799b00 ffff838c`12655d00 : fastfat!FatCommonRead+0x584
ffffb808`c3d4f700 fffff806`6d6d5209     : ffff950b`8840f920 ffff950b`85799b80 ffffb808`c3d50000 ffffb808`c3d4a000 : fastfat!FatFsdRead+0x1b8
ffffb808`c3d4f790 fffff80c`712d77c9     : ffff950b`84dc0001 00000000`00000000 ffff950b`8fb21a90 00000000`00000000 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x59
ffffb808`c3d4f7d0 fffff80c`712d6146     : ffffb808`c3d4f860 ffff950b`8489b2c0 00000000`00000000 000001a6`39325750 : FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x289
ffffb808`c3d4f840 fffff806`6d6d5209     : ffff950b`85799b80 ffff950b`8840f920 ffff950b`8840f920 fffff80c`712d5faf : FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0xb6
ffffb808`c3d4f8a0 fffff806`6dc83841     : ffffb808`c3d4fb80 ffff950b`8fb21a90 00000000`00000000 ffff950b`8fb21a90 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x59
ffffb808`c3d4f8e0 fffff806`6dc468e8     : ffff950b`00000000 ffff950b`8fb21a90 ffffb808`c3d4fb80 ffffb808`c3d4fb80 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1b1
ffffb808`c3d4f990 fffff806`6d8740f5     : 00000000`00000b34 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtReadFile+0x688
ffffb808`c3d4fa90 00007ffd`61cb08b4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
00000020`caef2038 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffd`61cb08b4

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!CcGetVirtualAddress+196103

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17763.3650

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  196103

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x34_nt!CcGetVirtualAddress

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {5b536b15-f12a-f73d-c33a-a39c3658f8ee}

Followup:     MachineOwner

1. Attaching the persistent disk in read-write mode works fine.
2. The memory, cpu and IO utilization prior to crash is at 10 %. cpu 4; mem 8gb and disk size: 100gb.
3. The application isn't writing on the persistent disk.

Comment: How exactly are you reading the files in your c# code?

Comment: Error messages, stack traces, etc are not helpful without the code that generated the errors.